# Typescript type for object-key to not start with specific character

Tags: typescript

In typescript you can force all keys in an object type to start with a certain character:

```js
type A = {
    [key: `@${string}`]: number
}
// okay:
const a1: A = {
  '@aaa': 10
}
// error:
const a2: A = {
  'aaa': 10
}
```

how do I do the opposite? I don't want my keys to start with `@`, like this:

```js
type A = {
    [key: ????]: number
}
// error:
const a1: A = {
  '@aaa': 10
}
// okay:
const a2: A = {
  'aaa': 10
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a union type that enables this behavior.

The first type simply defines an object where the key can be any string:

```
{ [k: string]: number }
```

For the second type, we can exclude keys that begin with "@" by indicating that they *may* be present, but using the "never" type to make assignment impossible:

```
{ [K in `@${string}`]?: never }
```

The resulting type definition would look like this:

```
type A = { [k: string]: number } & { [K in `@${string}`]?: never }

// error:
const a1: A = {
   '@aaa': 10
}

// okay:
const a2: A = {
   'aaa': 10
}
```

Comment: this answers the question, but how would I then add a specific key that starts with `@`to that type? For example, this doesn't work: type A = {
    [key: string]: number
  } & {
    [K in \`@${string}\`]?: never
  } & {
    '@title': string
  }